# Convert Custom Post Data to Javascript Array for Autocomplete

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, array, json, autocomplete

I am creating a metabox that utilizes jQuery Autocomplete to display custom post data.

How do I get this data:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'promo' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    foreach((get_the_category()) as $category);
    echo $category->cat_name. ' - ' .get_the_title();
endwhile;
```

...into a format that the following Autocomplete code can process?

```
echo '<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var promoList = '.json_encode($array) .';
        $( "#auto-promo" ).autocomplete({
            source: promoList
        });
    });
</script>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'promo' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
$promos = array();
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    foreach((get_the_category()) as $category);
    $promos[] = $category->cat_name. ' - ' .get_the_title();
endwhile;

echo 
    '<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            var promoList = '.json_encode($promos) .';
            $( "#auto-promo" ).autocomplete({
                source: promoList
            });
        });
    </script>';
```